# Installing Telerik to Visual Studio 2008 Toolbar throws System.Web.Extensions Error

Tags: telerik, windows-7-x64

I've just reformatted my machine and installed Windows 7.  I have Visual Studio 2008 Pro installed, and I've run all system updates.  The machine is telling me that I have .Net 2.0 SP2 installed as well as .Net 3.5 installed.

When I try to install my Telerik RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX to my toolbar, I get the following error.

> There was an error loading types from assembly 'E:\Visual Studio Extras\Controls\Telerik\RadControls ASPNET AJAX\2009.1.527\bin\Telerik.Web.UI.dll'
>   'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

I'd sure love to know what this means and how to overcome it!

Comment: @rockinthesixstring - is this a project you created in VS 2005 or is it a new project in VS 2008? Also, what version of Telerik?

Comment: It was all stuff migrated from my Vista install.  I posted my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Turns out I still had to install ASP.NET AJAX 1.0 into my system.  I suppose I thought this stuff was all integrated now.

I did a [Google Search](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Could+not+load+file+or+assembly+%27System.Web.Extensions%2C+Version%3D1.0.61025.0%2C+Culture%3Dneutral%2C+PublicKeyToken%3D31bf3856ad364e35%27+or+one+of+its+dependencies%22&hl=en&rls=com.microsoft%3Aen-us%3AIE-SearchBox&sa=2), and came up to the [asp.net forums](http://forums.asp.net/t/1135367.aspx) where I was directed to the [download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ca9d90fa-e8c9-42e3-aa19-08e2c027f5d6&displaylang=en).

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio 2008 and your project is targeting .NET 3.5, then you should reference the Telerik.Web.UI.dll assembly from the bin35 folder of the Telerik installation instead of bin. Then you will not need to have ASP.NET AJAX 1.0 installed.